# Script for Real Time Quotes from Fidelity

Tags: vba, excel

By using the Macro Recorder, and then making a few modifications, I have set up a macro to navigate to the Fidelity stock quote page for multiple quotes, and download delayed quotes.  This works well.  However, if I am logged in to Fidelity, and access that same page manually, I can obtain real-time quotes.  The "login" can take place either before or after I access the page.  I have not been able to figure out how to add the login process to the VBA routine that handles everything else. The macro recorder, started before I select the "get external data from Web option, does not pick up the login process when accessing that page for real time quotes.

Here is the part of the function that actually calls the stock quote page and requests the quotes:

```
With Worksheets("fidotemp").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Connection, _
    Destination:=Range("a1"))
    .name = Symbol
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = IIf(bSymbol, "12", "9")
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

The Connection parameter, named Connection, is the string which includes the particular page, along with a properly formatted string to obtain one or more quotes.  When multiple quotes are requested, the ticker symbols are '+' separated and limited to a 100 character length.

A sample Connection string might look like:

```
URL;https://fastquote.fidelity.com/webxpress/get_quote?QUOTE_TYPE=D&SID_VALUE_ID=VIP+SAN+E+MT+BCE+RAI+SNP+BP+MO+PTR&submit=Quote
```

Answer (score 0):

Is logging in from www.fidelity.com acceptable?  If so, does this get you in?

```
Sub test()
' open IE, navigate to the Fidelity log-in webpage of interest and loop until fully loaded
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    login_url = "https://www.fidelity.com"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate login_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 130
        .Height = 800
        .Width = 800
    End With

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

' Enter your username and pw
    IE.document.getElementById("temp_id").Value = "abcde"
    IE.document.getElementById("PIN").Value = "12345"

' Click the login button
    IE.document.getElementById("logButton").disabled = False
    IE.document.getElementById("logButton").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Almost works. I put your macro in a separate Sub so as not to confuse things. BUT the IE page returns "username or password ... not correct" UNLESS I put a break point at the Submit line in the macro, and then continue (F5); or I manually select the login button on the page.  Prior to this happening, IE.ReadyState is 4; and entering an Application.Wait for ten seconds (much longer than I really waited) does not --> successful login.  Thoughts?

Comment: seems like it only behaves correctly when I "step" through the macro (F8), not when I run it!

Comment: Tried your edited version and it behaves the same as the first -- successful login only I stop the Macro (with a breakpoint) and then select Login manually in the window; or if I stop the Sub with a break point and then "continue" the macro.  Also if I step through the whole thing; but I think one only has to "step" from just before the .submit line